# You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon

Tags: java, android, apk, kotlin, android-studio-2.3

I generated signed apk in android studio when i upload this apk to play store i get this message: "You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that expires farther into the future"

Comment: so, just do it.

Comment: What's the question? Just get a new certificate with an expirydate further into the future.

Comment: how? I already set the validity to 100 years but getting this message

Comment: Check your expiry years by giving the below command `keytool -list -v -keystore release-key.keystore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see the problem. In addition to creating a new certificate, you actually have to use it when you sign. If you use the old one it doesn't matter. And it isn't the keystore (a keystore can contain multiple certificates) that is the problem. you have to make sure you use the right alias, which is the part that actually holds the key. If you create a new alias but keep using the same old alias, it defeats the purpose.

So create a new certificate and make sure you actually use that one to sign the APK